# Finding the first element that satisfies a condition up to that element in stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of elements which potentially contain parentheses (in their `value` property). This code creates a list of the balanced occurrences (opening parentheses - closing parentheses) in each element, and then finds the first index where this balance is less than or equal to 0 (i.e. where all the parentheses are first closed).

```
List<Integer> parenthesisBalancePerElement = paragraphElements.stream()
                .map(paragraphElement -> checkBalancedOccurences(paragraphElement, "(", ")"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());  

int balance = 0;
int firstIndexWhereClosed;
for (firstIndexWhereClosed = 0; firstIndexWhereClosed < parenthesisBalancePerElement.size(); firstIndexWhereClosed++) {
    int elementBalance = parenthesisBalancePerElement.get(firstIndexWhereClosed);
    balance += elementBalance;
    if (balance <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    // use firstIndexWhereClosed
}
```

The second part of the code uses a for loop and is harder to read than the first IMO. Is there a cleaner way to do this, possibly by using streams?

Comment: This might be a good place to make the for loop into a function with a return (as soon as the match is found). Could be an anonymous function as well.

Comment: "where this balance is less than 0 (i.e. where all the parentheses are first closed)" - wouldn't you want the index where the balance first _becomes_ 0? What if they are well balanced? In that case you'd never have a balance < 0, would you?

Comment: What Integer is returned by checkBalancedOccurences? Is it the index of the opening parenthesis? The closing parenthesis? Something else?

Comment: My dataset is very irregular and very large and thus I think it's possible that I could reach < 0 in balanced occurences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of checking a `balance` as you iterate over elements makes this loop a stateful operation, which is discouraged for streams.

Your code is okay as is. Depending on your preference or your team's code style, you could change it slightly:

```
// find the index of the last operation that brings balance below 0
int balance = 0;
int firstIndexWhereClosed = 0;
for (; balance >= 0 && firstIndexWhereClosed < parenthesisBalancePerElement.size(); firstIndexWhereClosed++) {
    int elementBalance = parenthesisBalancePerElement.get(firstIndexWhereClosed);
    balance += elementBalance;
}
// use firstIndexWhereClosed
```